# Can't locate resources identified by URI '/mydll;component/subfolder/mainwindow.xaml' when loading the dll dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, assemblies

i'm having a problem with my project. In a library that i created, i have a subfolder which contains some view and viewmodels, but since those are in a class library, i don't have an app.xaml. This has always worked without a problem.

Recently i was tasked to encrypt that dll using a tool my company bought. What this tool does, is basically to decrypt and load dinamically the assembly. Now my problem is that, when i load dinamically the class library i was mentioning before, when a window has to be launched i get the following exception

> Can't locate resources identified by URI '/mydll;component/subfolder/mainwindow.xaml'

I've read that WPF has some problem when you load assemblies in this way, and a workaround is to add in the App.xaml a dummy global resources like the following:

```
<Application x:Class="TestWpfApp.App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> 
    <Application.Resources> 
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Dummy" Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush> 
    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

But i don't have an App.xaml. Is there a way on how i can solve this?

Currently my setup is the following:

I have a project which has a class AssemblyLoader. This class handle the following event:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(currentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

So every time the framework need something from a dll that is referenced, currentDomain_AssemblyResolve is called. If the assembly needed is encrypted, i use a dll to decrypt it and return the assemblies. I'm sure that the assembly is loaded because i can hit the "business" part. It throw an exception when he call InitializeComponent() inside the window

Comment: Pack URIs support resource files that are either compiled into the local assembly or compiled into an assembly that is referenced from the local assembly. If you load the assemblies dynamically, it won't work.

Comment: @mm8 so i can't load dinamically any assemblies that has xaml in it?

Comment: Yes, but you can't use pack URIs to located resources in these assemblies.